# Are there any reasons that index may not have a field's value in SOLR?

Tags: solr

In Elasticsearch, I see that there are reasons like `false`, `more than a particular length`, `malformed data` not stores the field's value in index.

In SOLR, are there any such options?

Comment: Do you have examples of what you want to achieve? You can add [update request processor chains](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/update-request-processors.html) that remove fields if the values doesn't match what you want them to be.

Comment: @MatsLindh The same scenarios as I mentioned. When length is higher/malformed data, I think is there a way to do this in SOLR?

Comment: Sure, but how do you want to decide what "malformed data" is? By default Solr (and ES) gives an exception and refuses to index the document if it's _really_ malformed. I'm also not sure what `false` means in your list. What do you want to achieve when these conditions fail? That nothing is indexed, that a certain length is indexed, that the value is removed? That's what I'm thinking about in regards to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MatsLindh In ES there are options that we can specify part of mapping. Can we do the same in while specifying schema?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you want to achieve when the assumption is broken. You can replace the value with an empty value by using a regular expression, or you can limit the length of tokens, but as far as I know you can't make the whole document fail indexing from the schema definition.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. Both based on lucene. That's what caused my expectation for an option.